# Inserting data into 4 tables at the same time in SQLite. How?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

My database has 1 table that has a 1 to many relationship with 3 other tables. The foreign key in the 3 other tables is the primary key from the "master" table.

So now when I commit to the database ideally I'd insert into the master table and then into the other three tables, but with the correct keys.

Why don't I just so that then?

Because the primary key in the master table is, in SQLite, a INTEGER PRIMARY KEY that isn't defined and so is an auto increment number. I've no idea what it will be when I insert into the table.

I know one way to do this is to insert my own primary key, but that means querying the table for the newest primary key first.

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered last_insert_rowid() ?

Comment: Depending on the API you are using, there is usually a way to get the value of an auto-increment number after the insert. For example, in JDBC there is Statement.getGeneratedKeys()

Comment: Yes, what bindings are you using to access SQLite? Normally what you'd do is create a transaction, and within that transaction first insert the master row, get the generated ID via `last_insert_rowid()`, then use that value to insert the three other rows, then commit the transaction.

Comment: Most DBMSes require the record to exist before setting up a relationship. You could probably do something using last_insert_rowid() but I doubt it would translate to any other DBMS.

Comment: Can I use last_insert_rowid() to get the primary key from the last inserted INSERT somehow and just the SQLite default rowid identifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read here: https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html (in most cases) the rowid and the integer in the primary key are the same:

*In SQLite, a column with type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY is an alias for the ROWID (except in WITHOUT ROWID tables) which is always a 64-bit signed integer.*

Comment: I missed that. Thanks.